# in nginx config, what is the meaning of caret ^ by itself?

Tags: configuration, nginx

A bit down on [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule#rewrite) nginx config reference page you'll see:

```
rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
```

What is the meaning of `^` above?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For rewrite, the first argument is the match pattern and only applies to the path portion of the url, not the domain. In regular expressions, `^` matches the beginning of the input. For example, `^/photos/.*$` would match paths beginning in '/photos/'. By itself, `^` is a shortcut for all paths (since they all have a beginning).

Comment: thx! turns out i could count to 2 (i counted 'permanent' as rewrite result)

Comment: actually, perhaps I spoke too soon. The [location doc](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) seem say that for a config to be interpreted as regex it must start with either ~ or ~* - otherwise the config is interpreted as a literal string. Am I reading that wrong or are the rules different for rewrite params? If the rules are the same, seems like '^' in the question should be interpreted as a literal, unless rewritten as '~ ^' - no?

Comment: That is only for the location config. If you look at the syntax for the rewrite config you listed above, you can see that the first argument is a regex and does not need a ~ prefix.